# Nuxt 3: createError not working in async try catch

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

`throw createError` is causing an `Uncaught (promise)` error when used within an async function using `try/catch`.

Try catch is returning the console.log, but not creating the error.

The error page is working fine outside of the async function.

The function:

```
const getContact = async () => {
    loading.value = true;
    try {
      const { data, error } = await client
        .from("contacts")
        .select()
        .eq("id", route.params.id);
      if (data) {
        contact.value = data[0];
      }
      if (!contact.value || error) {
        throw error;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Contact not found");
      throw createError({
        statusCode: 404,
        statusMessage: "Contact not found.",
        fatal: true,
      });
    } finally {
      loading.value = false;
    }
  };
  getContact();
```

Comment: Hm maybe `await throw createError`?

Comment: This throws an "error for experimental syntax needs to be enabled".

Comment: Nothing when you Google the initial error with throw?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing that has fixed it. The error in console is: ```uncaught (in promise) Error: Contact not found.```

Comment: I also get this error in terminal:

```[nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] H3Error: Contact not found.```

Comment: Also, it is allowing me to throw and alert: ```throw alert("Contact not found");```

Comment: UPDATE: Seems to be a bug in Nuxt 3, have filed a bug report

Comment: i'm facing the same issue have you got any work around solution? it seems nuxt 3 core bug

Comment: I think Nuxt 3 is not really ready to be used, too many things don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by replacing **statusMessage** to **message**.

I changed from:

```
throw createError({ statusCode: statusCode, statusMessage: "Page not found" })
```

to:

```
throw createError({ statusCode: statusCode, message: "Page not found" })
```

Not sure what is the difference (I could not find it in documentation), but seems it works fine.